# Python error I can't resolve: value of a series is ambiguous

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe called `result` that has the columns `date1` and `date2`. All other columns are being created as you see.

What I want is to create three columns based on the information on the column `date_diff`. One is called "less than 6 days" with 1 or 0 based on wether the element in `date_diff` is between 0 and 6. The other columns follow the same logic with the names "7-21 days" and "22+ days".

```
result['date_diff'] = result['date2'] - result['date1']
result['date_diff'] = result['date_diff'].dt.days
pd.to_numeric(result['date_diff'])


def menos_6dias(result):
    if 0 <= result['date_diff'] <= 6:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0

result['Pending < 6 days'] = result.apply(menos_6dias, axis=1)

def de_7_a_21dias(teste):
    if 7 <= result['date_diff'] <= 21:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0

result['7-21 days'] = result.apply(de_7_a_21dias, axis=1)

def mais_de_22dias(result):
    if result['date_diff'] >= 22:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0

result['22+ days'] = result.apply(mais_de_22dias, axis=1)

result.head()
```

There is an error I believe is due to the datatype of the column `date_diff`. Thus, I tried using `.dt.days` and `pd.to_numeric` but that didn't work. The error is:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-34-78fa25211501> in <module>()
     18         return 0
     19 
---> 20 result['7-21 days'] = result.apply(de_7_a_21dias, axis=1)
     21 
     22 def mais_de_22dias(result):

/Users/elachmann/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in apply(self, func, axis, broadcast, raw, reduce, args, **kwds)
   4358                         f, axis,
   4359                         reduce=reduce,
-> 4360                         ignore_failures=ignore_failures)
   4361             else:
   4362                 return self._apply_broadcast(f, axis)

/Users/elachmann/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in _apply_standard(self, func, axis, ignore_failures, reduce)
   4454             try:
   4455                 for i, v in enumerate(series_gen):
-> 4456                     results[i] = func(v)
   4457                     keys.append(v.name)
   4458             except Exception as e:

<ipython-input-34-78fa25211501> in de_7_a_21dias(teste)
     13 
     14 def de_7_a_21dias(teste):
---> 15     if 7 <= result['dias pendentes na acao'] <= 21:
     16         return 1
     17     else:

/Users/elachmann/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in __nonzero__(self)
    951         raise ValueError("The truth value of a {0} is ambiguous. "
    952                          "Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."
--> 953                          .format(self.__class__.__name__))
    954 
    955     __bool__ = __nonzero__

ValueError: ('The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().', 'occurred at index 0')
```

Here are the column headers of my dataframe: contract id || name || email || company || company state || user.active || contract.active || date1 || date2 || Pending || Answered || Rejected || Canceled || Inactive || Total Requests || fb rq id || aux

Comment: Which line is the error occurring?

Comment: Please post your df.head() here.

Comment: Just posted the lines where the error is occurring. Sorry my ignorance, just started with Python a week ago, but what is df.head()?

Comment: @Erik First 5 rows of your data frame :)

Comment: Of course I know, sorry.. that was stupid! I can't show the info, sorry! But here is the column header:
contract id || name || email || company || company state || user.active || contract.active || date1|| date2 || Pending || Answered || Rejected || Canceled || Inactive || Total equests || fb rq id || aux

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following DataFrame, `hd`.

```
            beer_servings
country
Armenia                21
Bulgaria              231
Cuba                   93
France                127
Iran                    0
Libya                   0
Mozambique             47
Peru                  163
Serbia                283
Thailand               99
Vanuatu                21
```

You probably know that a comparison with a Pandas column gives you a column of Booleans.

```
In [54]: pd.to_numeric(hd['beer_servings'] < 50)
Out[54]:
country
Armenia        True
Bulgaria      False
Cuba          False
France        False
Iran           True
Libya          True
Mozambique     True
Peru          False
Serbia        False
Thailand      False
Vanuatu        True
Name: beer_servings, dtype: bool
```

You may not know that the Series has an `astype` method that will let you convert the Boolean column to integer.

```
In [57]: (hd['beer_servings'] < 50).astype(int)
Out[57]:
country
Armenia       1
Bulgaria      0
Cuba          0
France        0
Iran          1
Libya         1
Mozambique    1
Peru          0
Serbia        0
Thailand      0
Vanuatu       1
Name: beer_servings, dtype: int64
```

I think you have demonstrated sufficient Pandas knowledge to take it from there, with the caveat that comparisons like `0 < df['column'] < 12` don't work, and have to be recast as `(df['column'] > 0) & (df['column'] < 12)` or similar.

Comment: Holden, it was working before when I was drafting the code. But then when I edited to have a cleaner code, I deleted something that it stopped working.  I still haven't fully understood. If I am comparing one value with another, won't it be a true or false statement?

Comment: You are comparing a column with a scalar, which is "broadcast" to each element of the column (a series). So the result is a series, which has no meaning in the content of an `if` statement - hence the message.

Comment: So I have to use a `for` and a `.loc` inside the `for` to to compare one element of the column with the scalar? Would that work? Or should I do a column with the same value as the scalar and compare a column with another column? Would that work?

Comment: That depends what you want, I'll edit a bit more detail into the reply.

Comment: I suspect with more detail on your problem it may turn out you won't need those `apply` calls.

Comment: Hey @holdenweb , just edited the question adding my primary objective of this code. I appreciate all your help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150266/discussion-between-holdenweb-and-erick).

Comment: Thank you so much @holdenweb , you're the best!! There was no need for the `.apply()` function, as you said above. What worked for me is `result['Pending < 6 days'] = pd.to_numeric(result['date_diff'] <= 6).astype(int) & pd.to_numeric(result['date_diff'] >= 0).astype(int)`